# move focus automatically in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this piece of code that creates a bunch of input fields (which can hold one char maximum):

```
renderInputs() {
    var products = []
    // some code that generates a randomNumber
    for (let p = 0; p < randomNumber; p++){
       products.push (<TextInput defaultValue="" maxLength={1} key={p}  onChangeText={(text) => this.handleChange(text, p)}></TextInput> );
    }
    return products
}
```

I want the focus to move automatically from one input field to the next one whenever the user fills one input field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store references to all inputs. Having them, you can focus to any of them. After content of input changes, you decide whether to move to next input or not.

Here is code, written without running and testing it - there is hight possibility it contains typos or even does not run. But the idea is there...

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
    inputRefs = []

    keepInputRef = (index) => {
        this.inputRefs[index] = null;
        return (ref) => {
            this.inputRefs[index] = ref;
        }
    }

    handleChange(text, p) {
        // do what you need.
        // then...
        // NOTE: `if` condition is completely off, won't work... Replace it with condition valid for your needs.
        if (something) {
            const nextInput = this.inputRefs[p + 1];
            if (nextInput) {
                nextInput.focus()
            }
        }
    }

    renderInputs() {
        var products = [];

        for (let p = 0; p < randomNumber; p++){
            products.push (
                <TextInput key={p} ref={this.keepInputRef(p)} defaultValue="" maxLength={1} onChangeText={(text) => this.handleChange(text, p)}></TextInput>
            );
        }

        return products
    }
}
```